# .htaccess RewriteRule makes 2 URL's available for same page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been trying to fix the url structure of my website for some time now.

All i need is for every URL with:

```
/main.php?mod=PageNameHere
```

to be rewritten and `301` redirected to:

```
/PageNameHere.html
```

I have already tried with this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.html$ /main.php?mod=$1 [L]
```

but all it has done is make the page available on both of the URL's. My navigation still links to the main.php?mod=PageNameHere URL so what I need is a way of forcing it to 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Tell apache to `Rewrite 301`. Otherwise it's just *mapping* the url

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)\.html$ /main.php?mod=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 separate Rewrite rules:

1. For internal forwarding `/PageNameHere.html` to `/main.php?mod=PageNameHere`, quite similar to what you already have.
2. For external redirecing `/main.php?mod=PageNameHere` to `/PageNameHere.html` with 301, something that you don't have at present.

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1. for internal forwarding
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.html$ /main.php?mod=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# 2. for external redirection
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+main\.php\?mod=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```